# Why can't I assign a derived class object to base class object in java?

Tags: java, oop, subclass, superclass

Here is the code:

```
class base
{
    public void abc()
    {
        System.out.print("what's up dude");
    }
}

class derived
{
    public void abc()
    {
        System.out.print("wad up ");
    }
}

public class superreftosub
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        base b=new base();
        derived d=new derived();
        base b=d;
        b.abc();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't assign objects to objects.

Comment: `derived` doesn't currently extend `base`.  You have two `b` variables declared in `main`.

Comment: You don't derive. Where is the extends?

Comment: Assigning one object to another just assigns the object reference (a pointer more or less). It does NOT copy member variables etc.

You need to read about cloning. From the first paragraph of the wiki for Java clone():

In Java, objects are manipulated through reference variables, and there is no operator for copying an object—the assignment operator duplicates the reference, not the object. The clone() method provides this missing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a superclass-subclass relation:

so:

```
class derived extends base {

    @Override
    public void abc() {
        System.out.print("wad up ");
    }
}
```

In some weakly-typed programming paradigms (like for instance duck-typing), this is indeed not necessary. Java is however strongly typed (well java is not fully strongly typed, but that's another discussion) and only allows assigning extended types and you can only give a new definition to a method using the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Technically you don't *have* to annotate your overriding method, but it's a good idea to always do it.

Comment: The `@Override` keyword makes sure that the compiler checks that there is a method in the superclass with that signature. It is not necessary but will decrease the number of mistakes. I agree with your comment, but one should try to give advice on how to produce good code.

Answer (score 0):

[Read about polymorphism! You just need to extend the base class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should use extends keyword to inherit a class,

Like

```
class derived extends base {
    //...
}
```